# How can I access the code of Firestore exception in google cloud function written in Typescript

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I have a Google Cloud Function written in Typescript and would like to access the code of the Firestore exception that I am getting.  How can I do that?

This is what I have right now:

```
    import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
    const db = admin.firestore();

   // Where do I import the Firestore exception from??

    try {
      await db.doc(`/users/123`).update({
        member
      });
    } catch (error) {
      // How do I typecast error to Firestore exception and 
      // how do I import this Firestore exception from?
      // Also what are all possible code values??

      if (err.code === 5){ // 5 means doc not found
        // do something
      }
    }
```

Comment: u can console.log the error and view it in your firebase console under functions

Comment: console logging the error does not tell me the type of error and does not help me in the if(error.code === 5){}

Comment: Firebase Admin is just a thin wrapper around the Google Cloud Firestore SDK, which has the same API.  The [update method](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/latest/firestore/documentreference#_google_cloud_firestore_DocumentReference_update_member_1_) doesn't say anything at all about any errors throw, nor are errors mentioned anywhere else in the linked API documentation. This suggests that what you're trying to do isn't supported. See also [this issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/2257).

Comment: @DougStevenson thanks for your help. I have already seen the github issue which is still open.  When I print the error, I can see that there is code of value 5.  But I am not able to determine the type of the error so that I can do something like error.code.  In Typescript you must know the type of error to access the code property.

Comment: That's not true.  You can cast an object to `any` to be able to access its data any way you like. Types are never required for anything at all (this is JavaScript after all) - they are a convenience for the developer.